# How to create a branch from a previous svn-revision using SmartGit?

Tags: git, svn, branching-and-merging, smartgit

I use SmartGit/HG with an old svn-repository. So it is not a git-repository.

I would like to create a new branch from a former revision in SmartGit. Is this possible?

In the end I would like to have a new folder on my local disk, where I have the full branch-files and in the old existing folder I will have the full trunk-files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, make sure you have cloned the SVN repository with SmartGit/Hg, not with git-svn (usually SmartGit/Hg will warn you about that when opening such a repository). Then:

- use **Branch|Checkout** to move to the revision from which you want to fork your branch,
- use **Branch|Add Branch** to create your new branch and select to switch to this branch,
- use **Remote|Push**. SmartGit/Hg will ask you how to push. Select **Push as New** here.

Now, your new branch will be present in the SVN repository and should show up in SmartGit/Hg's Log as a *remote* branch as well.

Comment: thanks, that worked. I also checked "use new branch" so now I am inside the branch in smartgit/hg. and the files locally are all reverted to that branch. How do I switch back to the main trunk in smartgit?

Comment: I would like to create a new folder on my local disk, where I have the full branch files and in the old folder I have the full trunk-files

Comment: Regarding the first question, use Check Out or Switch (from the Branches view). Regarding the second question, have two different clones of the repository.